# Why is my cron script to dump a MySQL database not executed?

Tags: bash, cron

I have the following `cron` job:

```
* * * * * /home/db_backups/test.sh
```

which runs fine and is executed every minute. If I check with `sudo grep \(CRON\) /var/log/syslog` I get the following:

```
Jun 23 11:30:01 analytics CRON[9301]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

However, if I change the executable file to `inreadobase_backup.sh`:

```
* * * * * /home/db_backups/inreadobase_backup.sh
```

the script is not run - I can see no records in the log.
The executable file if run by itself does the job with no error. Here is the content of the file:

```
sudo mysqldump -h example.com -u username -ppassword dbname | gzip > db.zip
```

Both executable files have execution permissions given to everyone.
Where should I look at to pinpoint the problem?

**EDIT**

The job runs and creates backups successfuly if I add to `sudo crontab -e` the following line:

```
*/5 * * * * mysqldump -h example.com -u username -ppassword dbname | gzip > db.zip
```

However, if I move the execution line `mysqldump... db.zip` to `inreadobase_backup.sh` file and specify it for the job:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/db_backups/inreadobase_backup.sh
```

the job doesn't create backups. I don't know how to check if it runs and what error it outputs if any.
If I simply execute `/home/db_backups/inreadobase_backup.sh` in command line the backup is created. And the only line the file contains is this:

```
mysqldump -h example.com -u username -ppassword dbname | gzip > db.zip
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you've added this as a crontab of your own user. The problem is that`cron` has no way of authenticating to `sudo` so it can't run your command. The simplest way around that is to add the crontab to `root`'s account instead:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then, add this line:

```
* * * * * mysqldump -h example.com -u username -ppassword dbname | gzip > db.zip
```

There's no need for a script for something so simple so you may as well add the command itself. Either way, you don't want to use `sudo` with it.

---

#### In response to your edit:

To rule out various possible complications, make `inreadobase_backup.sh` look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/mysqldump -h example.com -u username -ppassword dbname | /bin/gzip > /home/maximus/db.zip
```

Then, to capture any errors, redirect the error output of the script to a file by adding `2> file` to your `cron` line:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/db_backups/inreadobase_backup.sh 2> /tmp/cron.error
```

You can then check `/tmp/cron.error` for more details.

Comment: Thanks, now the job is running. I have more text in my execution file than this one line so I guess I will still need to run that execution file. Can I accomplish that?

Comment: @Maximus yes, just add with `sudo crontab -e` and don't use `sudo` with the script. Next time, please show us the two scripts you are comparing. The issue was relatively obvious here but you should always show us the actual code you are working with.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd condone the overuse of super-user rights. `sudo` is pretty well-suited for this kind of problem and one can create a `User_Alias` and `Cmnd_Alias` to allow one user to run a certain binary (or binaries) as another user, be it `root` or whichever. The point is, use the least privileges where ever you can.

Comment: @0xC0000022L setting up `sudoers` to allow execution might be a better idea, yes. Depends on what the script is doing.

Comment: @terdon, it doesn't work if I create the job this way `sudo crontab -e` - `* * * * * /home/db_backups/inreadobase_backup.sh`. Here is the contents of the executable file: `mysqldump -h example.com -u username -ppassword dbname | gzip > db.zip` - no `sudo` is used. What can be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @Maximus please [edit] your question instead of adding informatin in the comments. That way you can format it properly, and then ping the user you want to see it. Id that the _entire_ script? Is there no `#!/bin/sh` for example? What makes you think it is not run? Where are you looking for `db.zip`? Try giving a full path like `/home/you/db.zip` or similar.

Comment: @terdon, thanks for your suggestions, I've edited my original question to provide full information.

Comment: @Maximus see updated answer.

Comment: @terdon, thanks a lot! Now the job seems to be running OK. I changed only `inreadobase_backup.sh` and now I'm wondering what was missing. I guess I can remove some parts from the file and test it to see what was missing. Appreciate your help! Best, M

Comment: @maximus it probably was running but it created the db.zip in `/root` since that is the home directory of the root user and you did not provide a full path to it. Since the drontab was run as root, it defaults to root's $HOME.